What is Shambhavi Mahamudra?
I have watched several Sadhguru videos about Shambhavi Mahamudra and I did not understand:
what exactly is Shambhavi Mahamudra in simple words? How to practice it?
Thanks!

Shambhavi Mahamudra Kriya is a practice taught by Isha organisation. As far as I know, it cannot be learned from others and it has to be learned by only Isha trained teachers by joining to a program called Inner Engineering which can be done online or offline.
Please note Shambhavi Mudra is different from Shambhavi Mahamudra Kriya. It is a simple version of the more advanced Shambhavi Mahamudra Kriya.
Shambavi Mudra can be learnt online along with Upayoga here and can be practiced.
